# How do I make the blank areas not scrollable for iOS without hurting the game?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to improve my phaser game experience by enabling body-scroll-lock.

Currently, the code from the [official example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/scalemanager/full-screen-game) renders like this

[image]

where the areas pointed out by the red rectangles are scrollable, which is not good as the player might accidentally touch that area during the game.

I tried to change the config

```
scale: {
    mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
},
```

and I got

[image]

where the area pointed out by the red arrow is not scrollable though the game is now a mess.

I also tried the approach in [another tutorial](https://medium.com/jsdownunder/locking-body-scroll-for-all-devices-22def9615177).

```
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    document.body.ontouchend = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
    };
  </script>
```

none of them works.

this make things worse

```
body {
 position: fixed; 
}
```

How do I make the area not scrollable without hurting the game?

Comment: did you click on the black squares in the right top corner (the icon should change)? this should put the browser in the fullscreen mode. works on windows.

Comment: @winner_joiner Yes. I did click it on my iPhone and it doesn't work. This has been an unsupported feature on iOS for many years.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, sorry I didn't know, I'm an windows/android user, but I will think about a possible solution.

Comment: if you could find a solution yet, you could add the tags `html` and `css` to your question, maybe some html and css experts, could help with the positioning and preventing of the scroll action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would use *html* and *css* to solve it, but if it didn't work., here is an alternative solution.

You could use the `Phaser.Scale.FIT`*scale-mode* and just display the game scene, with the viewport I would keep the gameScene at the right scape/size.

**Here the Main Idea *(I think it is abit hacky, but should work)*:**

- you create a background Scene (you could set a background color or a blur effect like on horiziontal videos)
- On top of that Scene you display the actual Scene that contains the game

*(depending the size of the Game the `width` and `height` would have to be adjusted)*

> **And** I would additionally use the css-styles:  `html, body {padding:0; margin:0;}` just to be on the save side, that the canvas covers the whole window.

```js
var config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  scale: {
    mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
  },
  ...
  scene: [{
      key: 'background',
      create: function() {
        // Game size
        let width = 800;
        let height = 600;

        // Get The game Scene
        let gameScene = this.game.scene.getScene('gameScene');

        // Set Zone for the Game-Scene
        gameScene.parent = this.add.zone(this.cameras.main.centerX, this.cameras.main.centerY, width, height);
        
        // set the part of the scene that should be displayed
        gameScene.cameras.main
          .setViewport(gameScene.parent.x - gameScene.parent.width / 2, gameScene.parent.y - gameScene.parent.height / 2, gameScene.parent.width, gameScene.parent.height);
      },
    },
    GameScene
  ]
};
```

> ***Info:** just mentioning this part because it it not 100% obvious at first: `this.cameras.main.centerX`and `this.cameras.main.centerY` would give you the coordinates of center of the `scene`.*

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure if I use it correctly.  I just put a simple image in the scene and got  `Cannot set properties of null (setting 'parent')"` error, Here is the link. https://jsfiddle.net/shiqangpan/fgzextum/6/

Comment: @yaojp the problem is the `key:'GameScene'` (line 3) the name have to match(with the key in line 39), it should work if you change  line 3 to  `super({ key: 'gameScene' });`.

Comment: Thank you so much. The error have gone. The image doesn't display yet. Would you please take a look? here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/shiqangpan/fgzextum/8/

Comment: @yaojp sorry i missed that, you need to add the `active` configuration to the scene. line 3 should look like this:  `super({ key: 'gameScene', active: true});`